# Arrow on popViewController not going where I tell it

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller, cgrectmake

I have a UIPickerController that appears when you click a button though the arrow on it doesn't change position from the bottom even when I use `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp`.

```
- (IBAction)addPicture:(id)sender {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,650,768,1024);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

I guess this must be quite common

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the frame you are defining

Comment: Do you know what it is @J-MANMORGAN

Comment: Try calling [yourPopover setPopoverArrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown] after just to rule that out

Comment: Tried it though found that if I change some dimensions that I can get it on top though I don't know the dimensions of a popover so can't center it

Comment: There are no dimensions of a UIPopover...you are defining it by the elements you are placing within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a rect that has as width 768 and height 1024 starting on 0 and 650, so its a  huge element that is causing this unexpected behaviour. You should send as rect the rect of the button the user is pressing. Try this way instead.

```
- (IBAction)addPicture:(id)sender {
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```